# How to handle Quartz simple trigger when server is restarted

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using a Quartz simple trigger with RAMJobStore for scheduling in Spring MVC. It is working fine until the server is running. When I stop the server and rerun the program, previously scheduled job is not running.

Scenario:
Initially I scheduled the job to run at 1pm and 1:30pm respectively.The first job (1pm) is successfully executed, at 1:15 I stopped the server and restarted it. But the the job at 1:30 is not executed.

Comment: How do you schedule the Job on the Scheduler? Provide some details..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Quartz [doc](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09):

> it keeps all of its data in RAM.... The drawback is that when your application ends (or crashes) all of the scheduling information is lost

So, you have to switch to JDBCJobStore.

Comment: How will @Kainix answer help if it's a `RAMJobStore` as OP stated in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I was finding an answer to the similar problem and was able to solve it thanx to [Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14223110/4800126)'s answer but it is not a complete solution.
Taking your case into consideration I created a cron-expression with help of [freeformatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html#) so your code should look like this

```
try {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, current_hour_of_day);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            Date date = cal.getTime();

            //Run's job after every 30mins starting from 1pm
            CronScheduleBuilder cronScheduleBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/30 13 ? * * *").inTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            JobKey jobKey = JobKey.jobKey("testing");
            JobDetail quartzJob = JobBuilder.newJob(SchedulerTask.class)
                    .withIdentity(jobKey).build();
            TriggerBuilder<Trigger> trigger = newTrigger();
            trigger.withIdentity("testing");
            trigger.withSchedule(cronScheduleBuilder
                     //It fires the scheduler once for n number of missed events
                    .withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed());
            trigger.startAt(date);
            Trigger build = trigger.build();
            Scheduler quartzScheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            quartzScheduler.start();
            quartzScheduler.scheduleJob(quartzJob, build);
        } catch (SchedulerException | ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FeatureTesterMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
```

Tomasz's answer didn't have the part of `trigger.startAt()` due to which my missed schedules were not getting executed.
More on `withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()` policy read this [blog post](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html) by again, *Tomasz Nurkiewicz*

Comment: How will this help if it's a `RAMJobStore` as he stated in the question?

Comment: It's a common sense that he will have to store various aspects (viz scheduling timings, last scheduled event, etc) related to the scheduler somewhere like in db or in a file which can also be stored in RAM. Plus the answer that I provided is for `RAMJobStore`

Comment: Also @yishaiz are you aware of  [QTZ-283](https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-283) issue

Comment: 1. if he only uses RAMJobStore it will be erased when he stop the server. 2. if he uses a db or a file to store it then it's not longer in RAM only, and he better use the JDBCJobStore. 3. misfire isn't relevant here because both in 1pm and 1:30 pm the server was up, so there was no case of misfire.

Comment: anyway, the answer itself contains nice info, i'm just not sure it's answering this specific question..